# I tried to fetch data from firestore to chip widgets but then show "LateInitializationError". How I solve it?

Tags: flutter

I tried to fetch data from firestore to chip widgets but then show "LateInitializationError". And also chips should be can multi selection(select many chips). And also how to align 4 chips in a row like this example?I my code I think chips are show like ListView.

error..

[image]

I mean like this..

[image]

my code..

```
class uitry extends StatefulWidget {
  const uitry({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<uitry> createState() => _uitryState();
}

@override
Future<List<Words12>> fetchRecords() async {
  var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('12words').get();
  return mapRecords(records);
}

List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
  var _list = records.docs
      .map(
        (words12) => Words12(
          id: words12.id,
          wordName: words12['wordName'],
          categoryName: words12['categoryName'],
        ),
      )
      .toList();

  return _list;
}

late int defaultChoiceIndex;

@override
void initState() {
  initState();
  defaultChoiceIndex = 0;
}
```

```
child: SizedBox(
                      width: width * 0.94,
                      height: height * 0.30,
                      child: FutureBuilder<List<Words12>>(
                          future: fetchRecords(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                            } else {
                              List<Words12> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                              return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return (ChoiceChip(
                                    label: Text(data[index].wordName),
                                    selected: defaultChoiceIndex == index,
                                    selectedColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                                    onSelected: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        defaultChoiceIndex =
                                            value ? index : defaultChoiceIndex;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    // backgroundColor: color,
                                    elevation: 1,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 5.0),
                                  ));
                                },
                              );
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it .Now it working..
code

```
 SizedBox(
                      width: width * 0.94,
                      height: height * 0.30,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const SizedBox(height: 16),
                          Wrap(
                            children: hobbyList.map(
                              (hobby) {
                                bool isSelected = false;
                                if (selectedHobby!.contains(hobby)) {
                                  isSelected = true;
                                }
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    if (!selectedHobby!.contains(hobby)) {
                                      if (selectedHobby!.length < 50) {
                                        selectedHobby!.add(hobby);
                                        setState(() {});
                                        print(selectedHobby);
                                      }
                                    } else {
                                      selectedHobby!.removeWhere(
                                          (element) => element == hobby);
                                      setState(() {});
                                      print(selectedHobby);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 5, vertical: 4),
                                    child: Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 5, horizontal: 12),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: isSelected
                                              ? HexColor('#F5F185')
                                              : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(18),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              color: isSelected
                                                  ? HexColor('#F5F185')
                                                  : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                              width: 2)),
                                      child: Text(
                                        hobby,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: isSelected
                                                ? Colors.black
                                                : Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

```
class _uitryState extends State<uitry> {
  List<String> hobbyList = [
    'Shopping',
    'Brunch',
    'Music',
    'Road Trips',
    'Tea',
    'Trivia',
    'Comedy',
    'Clubbing',
    'Drinking',
    'Wine',
  ];

  List<String>? selectedHobby = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
void initState() {
  initState();
  defaultChoiceIndex = 0;
}
```

Should be:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  defaultChoiceIndex = 0;
}
```

I believe it will initialize your defaultChoiceIndex then.

For the alignment of chips: Wrap your ChoiceChip in the ListView.builder in a Row(), with a mainAxisAlignment of your choosing:

```
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
  ChoiceChip(etc.),
  ],
),
```